# If |a|> |a+b+c| prove that there is complex root such that |z|< 2

Tags: complex-analysis, quadratics

Let $a x^2 + b x +c =0$ be a quadratic equation where $|a|> |a+b+c| $, $a,b,c \in  \mathbb{R}$. Prove that this equation has at least one solution $ z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z| < 2$.

I don't know how to prove this, I noticed that $|a+b+c | = |f(1)|$, so $|a|> |f(1)|$, but I'm not sure if it helps. Also, $|z|= \frac{b^2}{4a^2} + \frac{ 4ac - b^2}{4 a^2}  <4\implies a c <4 a^2  $. Can anyone help? I would be greatly thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both roots $s,t$ are real then we have $a(x-s)(x-t)=ax^2-a(s+t)x+ast=0$. Now $$|a|>|a-a(s+t)+ast|\implies1>|1-s-t+st|=|(1-s)(1-t)|.$$ Clearly $|s|$ and $|t|$ cannot both be greater than $2$. The double root case is straightforward.

If both roots $s=u+iv$ and $t=u-iv$ are complex we have $$a(x-(u+iv))(x-(u-iv))=ax^2-2aux+a(u^2+v^2)=0.$$ Now $$|a|>|a-2au+a(u^2+v^2)|\implies1>|1-2u+(u^2+v^2)|.$$ If $|s|$ (and hence $|t|$) are greater than $2$ then $u^2+v^2>4$. Can you proceed?

Comment: Thank you for this answer! We have from the last inequality: $1> 1-2u+ u^2 +v^2> 0$ so $0> u^2+v^2 -2u \implies  
 u> 4/2 = 2$. Then  $1> (1-u)^2 + v^2 > (1-u)^2 >1 $ which is contradiction. Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct :)